# Complex roots of minimal polynomial using Galois

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, galois-theory, roots, minimal-polynomials

For the algebraic number $-3\sqrt6 + 3\sqrt[3]5$ I found the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ (degree = 6). So now I need to find complex roots of this polynomial, but I don't know how.
I have an idea: I need to look at automorphisms (elements of Galois group) of this polynomial, and observe that it isomorphic to some symmetric group etc. But still I don't know how to find these roots exactly.

Comment: The galois-group is $D_6$ here (not $S_6$, in which case the equation could not be solved by radicals) , which is actually solvable, hence the equation can be solved by radicals. But that does not mean that those expressions are easy to find. Apart from the conjugate of the given solution, I have no idea how to find the exact expression for the other roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other roots are the numbers of the form $\pm3\sqrt6+\left(-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)^k3\sqrt[3]5$, with $k\in\{0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Begin by seeing that 
$$\mathbb{Q}(-3\sqrt{6}+3\sqrt[3]{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt[3]{5}).$$

Now, this is not a normal field, since the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[3]{5}$ does not split. The normal closure of this would then need to be

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt[3]{5},\omega)$$

where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity.

This is an extension of degree $12$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and so we have $12$ automorphisms that fix $\mathbb{Q}$. We can see that these automorphisms are just the combinations of automorphisms moving around the roots of $X^3-1$, $X^3-5$, and $X^2-6$.

In particular, $\sqrt{6}$ can be mapped to $\sqrt{6}$ or to $-\sqrt{6}$.

$\sqrt[3]{5}$ can be mapped to $\omega\sqrt[3]{5}$, $\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{5}$ or $\sqrt[3]{5}$.

Since the Galois Group acts transitively on the roots of the minimal polynomial, this gives us all of the possibilities.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how can i explore complex roots not only over Q, but over for example $Q(\sqrt(6))$

Comment: Same idea. Get to the splitting field, compute galois group, check how it moves the elements. In this case the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ would be smaller since the galois group fixes $\sqrt{6}$.